# (Arquillian REST Extension) why webtarget is null in test method?

Tags: java, rest, junit, resteasy, jboss-arquillian

I try to use 'ArquillianResteasyResource' to inject WebTarget in my test, but WebTarget's variable remains null.

```
@Test  
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public void testWithWT(@ArquillianResteasyResource WebTarget webTarget) {  
    ......}
```

When I directly injects my class service, everything works fine!

```
@Test  
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public void testWithWT(@ArquillianResteasyResource MyService sv) {  
......}
```

my pom dependences :

> ```
> <dependency>
>       <groupId>junit</groupId>
>       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>       <version>4.12</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>   </dependency>
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.eu.ingwar.tools</groupId>
>       <artifactId>arquillian-suite-extension</artifactId>
>       <version>1.1.2</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>   </dependency>
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
>       <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>   </dependency>
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
>       <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
>       <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>   </dependency>
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
>       <artifactId>arquillian-rest-client-api</artifactId>
>       <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>   </dependency>
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
>       <artifactId>arquillian-rest-client-impl-3x</artifactId>
>       <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>   </dependency>
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
>       <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
>       <version>9.0.0.Final</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>   </dependency>
> ```

what is the problem with the WebTarget ?

any ideas ?

Best regards

Comment: Is this a server-side or client-side test? Which version of RestEasy is being used?

Comment: It is a server-side test. I use  the 3.0.11.Final version of RestEasy.

Comment: Certainly looks like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be late but if you want to inject `webTarget` in the test, you have to add `@RunAsClient` in the test method.

```
@Test  
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RunAsClient  
public void testWithWT(@ArquillianResteasyResource WebTarget webTarget) {}
```

Comment: It's correct but this do not solve the issue, me too for some reason get the WebTarget null

Comment: It depends on how you configure your server and how you launch the tests, on the server side ou the client side.  I cannot more info if you don't give more precision. My answer don't need a downvote for that

Comment: The correct answer should show the correct pom.xml to get arquillian work correctly and then the correct test implementation.

Comment: It's not because this answer does not correspond to your problem that you have to downvote it anyway. Configuring Arquillian is not an easy task. Anyway I  will update my answer to make sure the setup is correct

Comment: Thanks you! i'm sure this would help a lot of people

Answer (score 2):

I've created a [sample project on GitHub here](https://github.com/Lemmy4555/arquillian-rest-extension-embedded-server-example/tree/master) using rest-extension and an embedded instance of Glassfish.
I hope that would help.